# Windows phone Mango - Navigation in progress

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigationservice

One of the pages my in application lets a user take a picture and in the meanwhile, if image is being processed, later a NavigationService GoBack is called. Now, if user clicks power button on the phone, the phone goes to sleep, and then immediately clicks power again and navigate to app, it calls Navigation GoBack.

Sometimes it will throw an error saying `"Navigation is in progress"`, because the first user interface thread is still finishing navigation.

I have overloaded `NavigateTo` and `NavigateFrom` method. In `NavigationTO` I check if `NavigationMode.Back` I will execute GoBack.

If user clicks sleep and waits for a second or two and click on sleep again, it won't cause any issue since first user interface thread has finished executing Go Back.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
if(NavigationServive.CanGoBack)
    NavigationService.GoBack()
```